# Open a Link from App in JS

Tags: javascript, uwp

I'm making an app in JS running on Windows 10.

```
Windows.open("http://url");
```

Opens a new app window instead of the browser. How do I open a link to the default browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://url"));
```